# change default page size of firefox on linux base device

Tags: embedded-linux

I tried to change default page size of firefox on my linux based device by changing about:config and also by changing prefs.js, but it is not able to change it. I also added user.js file, but it will not affect it.

Comment: please help me to solve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: I also want to know how to open new window each time using command line in linux.